# Auto-update embedded tweet

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I am trying to make an embedded tweet, as shown in the following link:

> https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets

update itself with the latest tweet done by user X. The amount of tweets user X puts out are not really enough to create a full timeline. I am aware that there are other widgets available, however I would really like the above 'widget' update with the latest tweet. Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

While an Embedded Tweet code always references one Tweet in particular, below are the two steps which will let you dynamically retrieve an embed code and do what you are trying to achieve:

1. Using the Twitter API, you can retrieve the latest Tweet from a user directly from the [GET users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show) endpoint under the `status` nested object in the JSON response. Alternatively, you can also retrieve their entire timeline from [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) if you are interested in more Tweets than just the latest one.
2. Once you have the Tweet if want to embed, especially its ID, there is a section on the [Embedded Tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets) documentation titled *Embedded Tweets for Developers*. This shows you how to call an oEmbed endpoint on [GET statuses/oembed](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/oembed) and retrieve the HTML code to embed the Tweet.

Using the two above steps, you can dynamically embed the latest Tweet from a specified user on your page.